# How to calculate upper limit and lower limit in R?

Tags: r

[image: Formula for calculating the upper and lower limit]

I need to use this formula to calculate the upper limit and lower limit for the below vector. Please help..

```
 > a <- c(2150, 2261, 2018, 2217, 2074, 1986, 1662, 2324, 1591, 1700, 1809, 1824, 2026, 2169, 2072, 1463, 1484, 841, 851, 3742, 889, 905, 1203, 967, 1776, 1075, 1031)
 > a
 [1] 2150 2261 2018 2217 2074 1986 1662 2324 1591 1700 1809 1824 2026 2169 2072
 [16] 1463 1484  841  851 3742  889  905 1203  967 1776 1075 1031
```

Comment: Which bit can't you do?  Show us your attempts so far.

Comment: This looks more like a upper and lower prediction limit of a linear model...

Comment: Looks suspiciously homeworky, so I'll stick to a hint: `mean` and `diff` will be useful.

Comment: @RichieCotton I was too quick, it does look a bit "homeworky" - I had a colleague ask me a very similar question not that long ago.

Comment: @cgillespie: Don't worry too much; your answer is not right.

Comment: @Paul: hint: look at the sum indices and the divisors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a simple R formula:

```
UL = mean(a) + 2.66*sum(abs(diff(a)))/length(a)
LL = mean(a) - 2.66*sum(abs(diff(a)))/length(a)
```

The tricky part is |X_i - X_(i-1)| and so we use a few built-in R functions:

- `diff` gives X_i - X_(i-1)
- `abs` gives the absolute value

the first part of the formula is the mean and the +/- is just split up.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ctrl.limits <- c( LCL = mean(a) - 2.66*sum(abs(diff(a)))/length(a),
                   UCL = mean(a) + 2.66*sum(abs(diff(a)))/length(a) )
#> ctrl.limits
#      LCL       UCL 
# 495.1133 2920.4422
```

Why 2.66? It's a bit convoluted but boils down to being 3 (the number of specified standard deviations in either direction) times the ratio the expected range of a sample size of 2 drawn from a standard Normal to its standard deviation(=1). 'd2' is a function of the sample size. E(Ri ) = d2(n)σ

(See pg 55 (labeled 47) of [www.win.tue.nl/~adibucch/2WS10/SPClecturenotes.pdf](http://www.win.tue.nl/~adibucch/2WS10/SPClecturenotes.pdf) for a derivation.)